# .htaccess issue to rewrite url for codeigniter

Tags: php, .htaccess, codeigniter, mod-rewrite

i am using codeigniter in my project.
i have a url like https://www.domain.com/user/orderplace/any_number

i was trying to use htaccess rewrite so that if anyone hits my site with https other than above url then redirect to http://

i was trying

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^user/orderplace/(.*)$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.example.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

but its not working, i guess following line is not correct for my specified url
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^user/orderplace/(.*)$

can anyone help me in this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Add a `/` like `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/user/orderplace/(.*)$`

Some web servers may not support `RewriteCond %{HTTPS}` 
so try 
`RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-SSL}` insted.

Comment: i have tried both suggestion, not working at all. RewriteCond %{HTTPS} is working, i checked it. but mainly RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/user/orderplace/(.*)$ is not working.